# Create a document in memory?

Tags: itext

My goal is to send an email with a generated pdf file attached to it. This is in an ASP.Net page, and therefore, I would like to create the pdf file in memory (not physically on disk), and attached it to the email.

How can I create the pdf document in memory using iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code example that looks like it should work... (havent tried it myself)

http://www.nabble.com/Re%3A-Create-Pdfreader-from-Memory-Stream-p22792260.html

Answer (score 3):

Just "print" it to a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx). From there, you move it over to a byte array which you can attach to your email.